# Enumerate JavaScript objects functions?

Tags: javascript, reflection, internet-explorer-9

I wish to enumerate all the available functions of various JavaScript objects and even HTML elements created in JavaScript. For example the following works great in both Chrome and FireFox:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script>

        var object = document.createElement( "select" );

        for( var prop in object )
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += "" + prop + "; // " + typeof object[prop] + "<br/>";
        }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This outputs all the properties of the object including the functions available to that object, e.g.:

```
...
insertAdjacentHTML; // function
insertAdjacentText; // function
insertAdjacentElement; // function
getAttribute; // function
setAttribute; // function
removeAttribute; // function
getAttributeNode; // function
...
```

However this will not work in IE9, all you get are the string/number/object properties and never any of the function properties.

My question is how can I discover at run time what function names are exported by an object in IE9?

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE: adding a doctype gets this working as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <script>

        var object = document.createElement( "select" );

        for( var prop in object )
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += "" + prop + "; // " + typeof object[prop] + "<br/>";
        }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure this wont work on ie9 ... I made an example of your code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MPADp/1/) and works fine in ie9. The problem you are facing appears on ie8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code looks fine to me, and works OK in IE9 here.

http://jsbin.com/ivukus/edit#preview

Comment: Aha! thanks, I had to add <!DOCTYPE html> to get it working, cheers :)

Comment: will do, have to wait a few more minutes before it lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine in IE if you specify a [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration). Without a `DOCTYPE`, IE will render in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is essentially IE 5.5's behavior, which will greatly effect IE's Javascript support.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script>

        var object = document.createElement( "select" );

        for( var prop in object )
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += "" + prop + "; // " + typeof object[prop] + "<br/>";
        }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
form; // object
length; // number
multiple; // boolean
name; // string
options; // object
selectedIndex; // number
size; // number
type; // string
value; // string
dataFld; // string
dataFormatAs; // string
dataSrc; // string
add; // function
item; // function
namedItem; // function
remove; // function
.
.
.
```